# Intersection of two paraboloids

Tags: systems-of-equations, conic-sections, 3d

Consider two paraboloids. The first one is given by $x^2 + y^2 = z+5$. So, it intersects the x-y plane in the circle $x^2+y^2=5$. The second paraboloid is exactly the same as the first one, only shifted in the x-y plane. It's equation becomes $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=z+5$. From the figure below, it seems clear that the two should intersect in a parabola.

[image]

However, when we actually try and solve the two equations simultaneously, we get from the second equation
$$x^2 + y^2 -2x - 2y + 2 = z+5.$$
And substituting $x^2+y^2=z+5$ into this we get
$$2x+2y=2.$$

Now this is a linear function. However, the picture seems to suggest that it should be a parabola which is non-linear. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have obtained is the equation of the plane containing the intersection parabola.

The parabola in cartesian form is indeed defined by two different equations, as the following

- $x^2+y^2=z+5$
- $x+y=1$

You can parametrize it by

- $x=t$
- $y= 1-t$
- $z(t)=t^2+(1-t)^2-5=2t^2-2t-4$

Comment: But shouldn't I get the intersection parabola itself?

Comment: A parabola in 3D is defined by two equations: the equation of the plane of the parabola, and the equation of the parabola in the plane.

Comment: Think to the equation of a line in 3D you can’t write it in cartesian form by a single equation, you need two plane. Here it works in the same way.

Comment: You need to parametrize to find it in form of a single equation.

Comment: Intersecting the paraboloids we obtain the equation $x+y=1$ which represents a vertical plane containing the intersection of the two paraboloids. To define the intersection in cartesian form we can choose any pair of equation among the equations of the paraboloids and the plane. From the parametrixation is clear that the intersection is a parabola.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, exploiting  symmetry profitably, you can simply express the equations as
$$
\eqalign{
  & x^{\,2}  + y^{\,2}  = \left( {x - 1} \right)^{\,2}  + \left( {y - 1} \right)^{\,2}  = z + 5  \cr 
  & \left( {x - 1/2 + 1/2} \right)^{\,2}  + \left( {y - 1/2 + 1/2} \right)^{\,2}  = \left( {x - 1/2 - 1/2} \right)^{\,2}  + \left( {y - 1/2 - 1/2} \right)^{\,2}  = z + 5  \cr 
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  \left( {x - 1/2} \right)^{\,2}  + 1/4 + \left( {x - 1/2} \right) + \left( {y - 1/2} \right)^{\,2}  + 1/4 + \left( {y - 1/2} \right) = z + 5 \hfill \cr 
  \left( {x - 1/2} \right)^{\,2}  + 1/4 - \left( {x - 1/2} \right) + \left( {y - 1/2} \right)^{\,2}  + 1/4 - \left( {y - 1/2} \right) = z + 5 \hfill \cr}  \right.  \cr 
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  \left( {x - 1/2} \right)^{\,2}  + \left( {y - 1/2} \right)^{\,2}  = z + 9/2 \hfill \cr 
  \left( {x - 1/2} \right) + \left( {y - 1/2} \right) = 0 \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$

That is, a paraboloid with vertex in $(1/2,\, 1/2,\, -9/2)$ cut
by the diametral plane through the vertex.

Answer (score 0):

All sections of a paraboloid cut parallel to a plane containing the axis of symmetry is a parabola.. as is an intersection curve of two parabloids with parallel axes.